# Combining multiple async actions that have independent reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have two action files. `book_actions.js` and `author_actions.js`. They have their own reducers file as well.

When I fetch an author, it returns me a list of book ids. I would then like to fetch all these books.

```
author_actions.js
export const fetchAuthorAndBooks = (authorId) => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
fetchAuthor(authorId).then((author) => {
  author.bookIds.each((id) => {
      dispatch(fetchBook(id))
  })  
});

}
```

I want to wait for the author and the book fetching to complete before rendering anything on screen. To accopmbilish this I was going
to add a loading flag on each reducer state. Then when nothing is loading, render the components with all the data that was returned

Is this the correct way to handle multiple async calls on different actions files? It seems wrong to add a loading property in each reducer
just for this. Should I be doing this in `author_actions.js` or a container component which dispatches these actions?

Answer (score 2):

I would check if the API you are using has an endpoint like `authors/:id/books`. If an author has 100 books, I don't think it is very performant to make 100 API calls. There should be an endpoint like I described that would return all of the books for the author.

An alternative approach if you cannot access an endpoint like that, would be to try using something like `Promise.all`, which only returns one Promise depending on the result of several Promises passed to it. Perhaps you could create a new method that accepts an array of the book `id`'s:

```
function fetchAuthorBooks(ids) {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id => axios.get(`/books/${id}`)))
}
```

usage:

```
fetchAuthorBooks(author.bookIds).then((books) => {
  // the array of books
}).catch((err) => {
  // one of the requests failed
})
```

Hopefully, this gives you some direction! I would really lean towards finding out if that endpoint is available.